# How to adapt TextVectorization layer on tf.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-preprocessing

I load my dataset like this:

```py
self.train_ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
            self.config["input_paths"]["data"]["train"],
            batch_size=self.params["batch_size"],
            shuffle=False,
            label_name="tags",
            num_epochs=1,
        )
```

My TextVectorization layer looks like this:

```py
vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
            standardize=code_standaridization,
            split="whitespace",
            output_mode="int",
            output_sequence_length=params["input_dim"],
            max_tokens=100_000,
        )
```

And I thought this is going to be enough:

```py
vectorizer.adapt(data_provider.train_ds)
```

But its not, I have this error:

```
TypeError: Expected string, but got Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=string) of type 'Tensor'.
```

Can I somehow adapt my vectorizer on TensorFlow dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is that you use `batch_size` in your `train_ds` without `.unbatch()` when you try to adapt.

You have to do:

```
vectorizer.adapt(train_ds.unbatch().map(lambda x, y: x).batch(BATCH_SIZE))
```

The `.unbatch()` solves the error that you are currently seeing and the `.map()` is needed because the TextVectorization layer operates on batches of strings so you need to get them from your dataset